# パーソナル Redmine をセキュアかつ低コストで構築

Tags: redmine

現在、ローカルマシンの Docker 上にて、自分専用の Redmine を試用中です。
大変便利なので、外出先からも利用したくなりました。

そこで、いくつか方法を検討してみたのですが、全くの素人ゆえ、安全面や経済面での不安が拭えません。アドバイス等を頂ければ幸いです。

### 検討した方法

1. VPS や PaaS をレンタルして構築

   - デメリット

     - 運用コストがかかる
     - 制限がある (特に PaaS
     - 海外のセービスを利用する場合は速度等が気になる
   - メリット

     - ある程度のセキュリティは保障される? (もちろんアプリケーション自体は自己責任だろうが
2. 自宅鯖で構築・公開

   - au ひかり回線なので制約が多く、イレギュラーな設定をしなければならない
   - よって、経済的にも学習的にも高コストかもしれない
3. 自宅鯖は公開せずに VPN で接続 (今のところ本命)

   - VPN 自体は、今回の件とは別にチャレンジしてみたいと以前から思っていたので好都合。
   - 2 と同様の問題点があるが、VPN でのアクセスなのでアプリケーション自体のセキュリティなどは、そんなに心配しなくても良い?

### 求めるもの

1. どこからでもアクセスできる自分専用の Redmine

   - なるべく新しい Redmine を使いたい
   - できれば Docker 上で
2. できるだけセキュアに

   - プライベートな情報を扱うので
3. できるだけ低コストで

   - 初期投資は惜しみません
   - 運用コストはゼロに近づけたい
4. 学習コストも低い方がありがたい

   - 今すぐにでも欲しいので... ＞＜

### 当方の知識・経験

- Web アプリケーションをローカルや Docker 上で **とりあえず** 動かすことはできます。

  - e.g. gollum, media wiki, その他 Python 製の小規模なモノとか
  - 公開を前提とした Web アプリケーションの構築は未経験
  - よって、Web アプリケーションのセキュリティなどは知識ゼロ
- ネットワーク関連の知識もほぼゼロ

Comment: SaaSが一番お手軽だと思いますが、これは値段が・・・。 http://hosting.redmine.jp/

Comment: この手の問題って、最終的には koyudoon さんが何にいくらまで出せるか、という共有ができないので、ここでは解決できない気がします。コストなんて毎年でも変わりますから。

Comment: 最終的な判断はコストになりますが、そもそもどのような手法があり、それぞれのメリット・デメリットは何なのか? を理解できていなかったので、この様な曖昧な質問となりました。m(_ _)m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どのような形であろうと公開サーバを運用するにはそれなりの知識が必要です。

それがないのであれば、VPSだろうとクラウドだろうと自宅サーバだろうとサーバの公開は選択肢になり得ません。

VPNがルータの機能で実現できるのであれば、よっぽどおかしなことをしない限り危険な状態にはなりにくいので、比較的ましな選択肢と言えるでしょう。ただし、VPNの公開もサーバの公開の一種ではあるので、十分に内容を理解しておこなってください。

追記
上記で、「VPNが**ルータの機能で実現できるのであれば**」と書いているのに注意してください。ソフトウェアによるVPNサーバの運用にはセキュリティ確保のために一定の知識が必要なので、それをやるぐらいであればRedmineを直接公開した方が遙かにましです。

Comment: "どのような形であろうと公開サーバを運用するにはそれなりの知識が必要です" 一番懸念していた点です。やはり、学習コストを考えると VPN が一番近道ですかね。

Answer (score 1):

自宅サーバーの電気代やメンテナンスのコストを考えると
さくらVPSの小さいのを使うのがよさそうな気がしました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。簡単に比較してみました。/ VPS のメリット (宅鯖デメリット) ... 火災や雷に強い, 故障に強い, 構築・運用の経験が後に役立つかも / VPS のデメリット (宅鯖メリット) ... 大容量のストレージが必要だと高くつく, 同上だが、ハードウェアの縛り, バックアップは必須(過去にバックアップを含めた全消去事例がある / ※電気代に関しては、運用の工夫で宅鯖でも低コストに抑えることができる??  / [さくらの VPS](http://vps.sakura.ad.jp/specification/) 2週間お試しできるので良さげですね。しかし、一番安いプランでも年間5,000円以上。Redmine しか動かさないのであれば割高かな...

Comment: @koyudoon バックアップの必要性は宅鯖でも同じことですし、むしろ自前で管理するほうが事故で飛ぶ可能性が高いかと思います。ストレージは一番安いので20GBですが、OS分を抜いても10GB以上使う予定があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 現在、考えている用途は、テキストメインの Redmine や wiki なので十分間に合いそうです。が、将来的に画像等も添付したくなったとき厳しいかもしれないですね。

Answer (score 1):

比較的学習コストが低く
自宅サーバ運用でVPNを選択するなら
Softether VPN辺りですか。

ルータ、FW、ポート設定さえできれば「何となく」構築できます。

私の自宅サーバ(WindowsServer)も「何となく」構築しVPNでアクセスできる環境にしてあります。

この場合「何となく」で終わらず、よりセキュアになるようにしていくのが望ましいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Dockerとは異なりますが、当方、自分専用のRedmineをどこからでもアクセスできる環境を無料で運用しております。
私はHerokuというクラウドサービスが無料でWebアプリを5つまで公開できるのでそちらを活用しております。
自分でサーバーを立てる必要もないので初期コストも必要ありません。

https://dashboard.heroku.com/

アプリをデプロイするのに多少、gitの知識が必要ですが、簡単なのでおすすめです。
Heroku Redmine で検索してみて下さい。
プラグイン導入もgitのpushでできるので簡単です。
アプリの再起動もHerokuのアプリをインストールしていれば、

```
# heroku restart
```

だけでできるので非常に楽です。

デプロイの変更履歴がgitでバージョン管理できる点も気に入ってます。

Answer (score 0):

さくらVPSも悪くないですが、FWをOSレベルで確保する必要があるので、iptables等の設定に不安がある場合は、若干めんどくさいかもしれません。

私としては、VPSと別にフロントエンドにFWが存在する、AWSやさくらのクラウドIaaS系サービスをお勧めします。

#### IaaS系サービス例

- aws
- さくらのクラウド
- IDCFクラウド
- cloudn

さくらのクラウドだと割高になってしまうので、無料枠があればaws、そうでなければIDCFのLight-S1で試してみるのが良いかと。

(ぶっちゃけAWSは機能多すぎてよくわからんってなる可能性もあるので、IDCFクラウドでさくっと試してみるのはアリだと思います。)

バックアップについても、スナップショットやオブジェクトストレージが利用できるので必要に応じて選択できます。

cloudnは利用した事ありませんが、ワンコインからのプランもあってわりと良さそうに見えます。

Comment: まず、IaaS, PaaS, SaaS などの区別がついていなかったので勉強になりました。[IDCFクラウド](http://www.idcf.jp/cloud/price.html)は料金体系が魅力的ですね。これは有力候補になりそうです。

Answer (score 0):

> 運用コストはゼロに近づけたい

ということなので、自分だけが使えれば良いというのであればAmazon EC2のように使用しない時にサーバーを簡単に止めて課金しないようにできるのが良いと思います。
サーバーが止まっていれば不正アクセスのしようがないので安全ですし。